# Android: detect when app finishes installation

Tags: android, installation

I want to detect when an application in android has finished installation without using a brodcast receiver. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might be able to read logs instead , but that requires "bad" permission , which is no longer supported as of API 16 (jelly bean) .

Comment: mmmm ok, it means in have to use broadcast receiver?

Comment: it's much better than anything else that i can think of . what's so bad with brodcast receiver anyway? you can register and unregister to it whenever you wish.

Comment: every time I am clicking on an app to install it, I register a corresponding receiver. But I don't know when to unregister it

Comment: well if you have no idea when such an event will occur , you need to set it either in the manifest or use a service that keeps running and listening to this event.